# Reading XML data in C# with XmlTextReader

Tags: c#, xml

I have this type of XML format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
 <descriptor>
    <feature>5.12</feature>
    <feature>0.0002827647</feature>
    <feature>0.0147277</feature>
    <feature>0.00037847</feature>
 </descriptor>
</root>
```

using the MSDN example I'm trying to read it like this:

```
Matrix<float> ObjectDescriptors = new Matrix<float>(200, 4);
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("descriptors.xml");
        int i = -1;
        int ii = 0;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.Name == "feature" && ii < 4)
            {
                String currStr = reader.Value;
                ObjectDescriptors[i, ii] = Convert.ToSingle(currStr);                    
                ii++;
                if (ii == 4) ii = 0;
            }
            else if (reader.Name == "descriptor") i++;
        }
```

I get the following error for the line

```
AgrObjectDescriptors[i, ii] = Convert.ToSingle(currStr);
```

An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Seems like the node "feature" is being detected (reader = {Element, Name="feature"}) but its content is empty ("")

using System.Xml;  is included

Would be nice if anyone tells me why this error occurs!
Thank you!

Comment: replacedbyObjectDescriptors[i, ii] = reader.ReadElementContentAsFloat(); solved the problem

Comment: your reader.Value is empty ..cast it to a float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reader.Read` will go through each part of the XML, and the elements are not the same as the text that is inside them.

So once you find the element you are looking for, you must read the text inside.

Try replacing:

```
String currStr = reader.Value;
```

With:

```
String currStr = reader.ReadString();
```

Answer (score 0):

replaced by

```
ObjectDescriptors[i, ii] = reader.ReadElementContentAsFloat();
```

solved the problem. question closed.